# Appium - Android - Error: spawn appium ENOENT

Tags: webdriver-io, appium-android

I am trying to run android tests with the command `node ./node_modules/.bin/wdio config/wdio.android.browser.conf.js` and getting the following error:

```
me$ node ./node_modules/.bin/wdio config/wdio.android.browser.conf.js
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn appium ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:362:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:696:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

I have the following versions in my package.json:

```
"wdio-appium-service": "^0.2.3",
"appium": "^1.12.1",
```

Please let me know what other info I can provide.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I think I figured it out... in config/wdio.android.browser.conf.js I had `services: [ 'appium' ]`, and trying to run just `appium` on my machine wasn't working.  I installed appium globally with `npm install -g appium` and that made it work.  I think I can point services to the appium in the local node_modules directory and maybe it would run it from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows OS, appium section in your config file shall include command: 'appium.cmd' like this :

```
{
  services: ['appium'],
  appium: {
    command: 'appium.cmd',
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs due to 2 possible issues:

1) JAVAHOME variable is not correctly set for appium to start & run tests.

-> Check that `JAVAHOME` is correctly set and path points to the correct file.

2) There could have been some errors during Appium installation.

-> Try reinstalling appium using `npm install -g appium` command and ensure that appium is installed without any errors.

Obviously, run `npm install` to check and install any missing dependencies too.